# Fetch data based on option selected to be condition to select certain data laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Basically, I am working on inventory project where I am suppose to fetch data from different tables according to user input, so I have 8 States and for every state there is a station and every station has 3 departments where there is software asset and hardware asset for every major department of the three.

I want to take user, choose and take that data to determine which state table is joining to be called and then I want to select certain column based on sattion_id, department_id, asset_id, where these three columns are columns in state table. I am using data table to view my data to the client.

Here is my js file for more details:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="governorate"]').on('change', function() {
        var governorateID = $(this).val();

        if (governorateID) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/getStation/' + governorateID,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('select[name="station"]').empty();
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        $('select[name="station"]').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('select[name="station"]').empty();
        }
    });
});

$("#search").on("click", function() {
    var governorate = $('#governorate option:selected').val();
    var link = document.getElementById("station").value;
    var department = $('#department option:selected').val();
    var assetType = $('#assetType option:selected').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.href = "getData/" + governorate + link + department + assetType

    });

});
```

Here is my controller:

```
    
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        //South_batinah_hw is example of a table where the I need now to take user selection to comare with
        //the values in the table to fetch the correct columns
        $data = South_batinah_hw::select('Asset_ID','Asset_Type','Asset_Name','Asset_Location',
              'Asset_Owner', 'OEM_Vendor_Name', 'Model_No', 'Serial_No',
              'Location_and_Rack_Details', 'A_Availability', 'I_Integrity', 
              'C_Confidentiality', 'Date_Of_Asset_Deployed', 
              'Date_Of_Asset_Decommissioned',
              'Date_of_End_of_Life', 'Maintenance_Status', 'SLA', 'Purpose')::where('station_id', $station_id)
            ->where('department_id', $department_id)
            ->where('assets_id',$assetType_id)->get();
            return DataTables::of($data)
                    ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                        $button = '<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button>';
                        $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>';
                        return $button;
                    })
                    ->rawColumns(['action'])
                    ->make(true);
        }
        return view('search.data');
    }
```

---

and here is my search/data.blade.php:

```
<th width="7%">Asset_ID</th>
<th width="5%">Asset Type</th>
<th width="5%">Asset Name</th>
<th width="2%">Asset Location</th>
<th>Asset Owner</th>
<th width="2%">OEM Vendor Name</th>
<th width="3%">Model No</th>
<th width="3%">Serial No</th>
<th width="20%">Location and Rack Details</th>
<th>Availability</th>
<th>Integrity</th>
<th>Confidentiality</th>
<th width="2%">Asset Deployed Date</th>
<th width="2%">Asset Decommissioned Date</th>
<th>Expiring Date</th>
<th width="2%">Maintenance Status</th>
<th>SLA</th>
<th width="5%">Purpose</th>
<th width="10%">Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
   <tr>
   </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
<!-- /.card-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.card -->
</div>
<!-- /.col -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
</section>
<!-- /.content -->
</div>
```

I need to figure out how can I use Ajax to store the required data and then send them to controller to fetch the needed data from the table in sql.

Answer (score 1):

```
let payload = {
                        fname: this.fname,
                        lname:this.lname,
                        email: this.email,
                        comments: this.comments,
                        emailTo: this.manager,
                        clubName: this.club_slug
                    };

$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: `${this.transit_url}/some/route`,
     data: payload,
     success: function(r) {
     console.log('Response from Server - ', r);
     },
     error: function (e) {
      console.log('Response from Server - ', e);
        
     },
});
```

Use the above snippet as an outline. If you're saving data with the request, then it needs to be the POST method. You may return whatever you'd like and access it in Ajax success:

Of course, in your case, you'll be using Jquery rather than Vue.

You'll need to take whatever value the user chooses from the Select input, make a POST request where you'll determine which state table is going to be called. Then query the table, format your data, and return it.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, Can you follow my code below?? I am still getting an error with datatable

Comment: Besides, I don't want to save user input to database. I just want to able to pass them through a ,method in the controller which will customize selecting query for the required data to be retrieved form database.

Answer (score 1):

So I am trying to follow, so basically I have a search button in my search/index.blade.php and I am using this scripit to collect user selection

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
                     $('select[name="governorate"]').on('change',function(){
                     var governorateID= $(this).val();

                     if (governorateID){
                        $.ajax({
                              url:'/getStation/' +governorateID,
                             type: "GET",
                             dataType: "json",
                             success:function(data)
                             {
                           $('select[name="station"]').empty();
                          $.each(data, function(key,value){
                             $('select[name="station"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                          });
                         }
                      });
                      }
                     else
                      {
                          $('select[name="station"]').empty();
                       }
                 });
                });
             
            
                     $("#search").on("click", function() {
                        var governorate = $('#governorate option:selected').val();
                        var link = document.getElementById("station").value;     
                        var department = $('#department option:selected').val();
                        var assetType = $('#assetType option:selected').val();

                      
                           $.ajax({
                              url: window.location.href= "getData/"+ governorate + link  + department + assetType

                           });

                     });
```

and I want to include this scripit with this one from search/data.blade.php

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var fovernorate_id = $(this).val();
  var station_id = $(this).val();
  var department_id = $(this).val();
  var assets_id = $(this).val();
  
 $('#example1').DataTable({
  'Processing': true,
  'ServerSide': true,

  'scrollY':  "400px",
        'scrollX':  true,
        'scrollCollapse': true,
        'paging':         false,
        'fixedColumns':   {
            leftColumns: 2
        },
  ajax: {
   url: "{{ route('SouthBatinahHW.index') }}",
  },
  columns: [
   {
    data: 'Asset_ID', name: 'Asset_ID'},
   {data: 'Asset_Type', name: 'Asset_Type' }, {data: 'Asset_Name', name: 'Asset_Name'},
   {data: 'Asset_Location', name: 'Asset_Location' }, {data: 'Asset_Owner', name: 'Asset_Owner'},
   {data: 'OEM_Vendor_Name', name: 'OEM_Vendor_Name' }, {data: 'Model_No', name: 'Model_No'},
   {data: 'Serial_No', name: 'Serial_No' }, {
    data: 'Location_and_Rack_Details', name: 'Location_and_Rack_Details'},
   {data: 'A_Availability', name: 'A_Availability' },{ data: 'I_Integrity', name: 'I_Integrity'},
   {data: 'C_Confidentiality', name: 'C_Confidentiality' },{ data: 'Date_Of_Asset_Deployed', 
   name: 'Date_Of_Asset_Deployed'},
   {data: 'Date_Of_Asset_Decommissioned', name: 'Date_Of_Asset_Decommissioned' }, 
   {data: 'Date_of_End_of_Life', name: 'Date_of_End_of_Life'},
   {data: 'Maintenance_Status', name: 'Maintenance_Status' },{ data: 'SLA', name: 'SLA'},
   {data: 'Purpose', name: 'Purpose' },
   {data: 'action',
    name: 'action',
    orderable: false
   }
  ]
 });

 $('#create_record').click(function(){
  $('.modal-title').text('Add New Record');
  $('#action_button').val('Add');
  $('#action').val('Add');
  $('#form_result').html('');

  $('#formModal').modal('show');
 });

});
</script>
```

and after that I want to have something like this in my controller

```js
public function index(Request $request, $governorate_id,$station_id, $department_id, $assetType_id)
    {

  

        if($request->ajax())
        {
            //South_batinah_hw is example of a table where the I need now to take user selection to comare with
            //the values in the table to fetch the correct columns
            $data = South_batinah_hw::all('Asset_ID','Asset_Type','Asset_Name','Asset_Location',
            'Asset_Owner', 'OEM_Vendor_Name', 'Model_No', 'Serial_No',
            'Location_and_Rack_Details', 'A_Availability', 'I_Integrity', 
            'C_Confidentiality', 'Date_Of_Asset_Deployed', 'Date_Of_Asset_Decommissioned',
            'Date_of_End_of_Life', 'Maintenance_Status', 'SLA', 'Purpose')->where('station_id', $station_id)
            ->where('department_id', $department_id)
            ->where('assets_id',$assetType_id)->get();;
            return DataTables::of($data)
                    ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                        $button = '<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button>';
                        $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>';
                        return $button;
                    })
                    ->rawColumns(['action'])
                    ->make(true);
        }
        return view('search.data');
    }
```